# Query not returning expected data

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-server-2017, sql-null

I'm looking for an explanation for why 1 of the following 3 queries aren't returning what I am expecting.

```
-- Query 1
SELECT ANNo, ANCpr
FROM Anmodning
WHERE LEFT(ANCpr,6) + '-' + RIGHT(ANCpr,4) NOT IN (SELECT PSCpr FROM Person)

-- Query 2
SELECT ANNo, ANCpr
FROM Anmodning a
LEFT JOIN Person p ON p.PSCpr = LEFT(a.ANCpr,6) + '-' + RIGHT(a.ANCpr,4)
WHERE p.PSNo IS NULL

-- Query 3
SELECT ANNo, ANCpr
FROM Anmodning
WHERE ANNo NOT IN
(
  SELECT ANNo
  FROM Anmodning
  WHERE LEFT(ANCpr,6) + '-' + RIGHT(ANCpr,4) IN (SELECT PSCpr FROM Person)
)
```

Assume the following:
Anmodning with ANNo=1, ANCpr=1111112222
And the Person table **doesn't** have a row with PSCpr=111111-2222
Queries are executed in Management Studio against a SQL Server 2017.

Queries 2 and 3 returns the Anmodning row as expected but query 1 does not.
Why is that?

Comment: Take the time to post DDL and DML statements to go with your queries so we can reproduce the issue and explain exactly what's happening here.

Comment: Also, What *are* yo expecting here? For all the queries to be the same?

Comment: With the limited information provided, all 3 queries return the same result for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue with the first query is a null-safety problem. If there are null values in `Person(PSCpr)`, then the `not in` condition filters out all `Anmodning` rows, regardless of other values in `Person`.

Consider this simple example:

```
select 1 where 1 not in (select 2 union all select null)
```

Returns no rows, while:

```
select 1 where 1 not in (select 2 union all select 3)
```

Returns `1` as you would expect.

This problem does not happen when you use `left join`, as in the second query.

You could also phrase this with `not exists`, which is `null`-safe, which I would recommend here:

```
SELECT ANNo, ANCpr
FROM Anmodning a
WHERE NOT EXITS (SELECT 1 FROM Person p WHERE p.PSCpr = LEFT(a.ANCpr,6) + '-' + RIGHT(a.ANCpr,4))
```

Comment: Of course. I didn't even consider null values at all :)